# Opening a file gives segfault in program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

I'm new to C programing and I have problems understanding how to use fopen, fseek, freopen functions and how to read/write a linked-list to file.

Here is the code from :

```
struct data used_servers(){
    struct data server_settings;

    s_type *head;
    s_type *actual;
    int r_id;
    char r_host[16];
    char r_port_inc[8];
    FILE *f;
    long size;
    head = NULL;

    char select_inc[10];
    int select;
    int count = 0;

    f=fopen("./config/config.init", "r");

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    if(size==0){
        printf(" There are no servers to choose from. Proceeding to set up a new connection!\n");
        server_settings = initialize_server();

        head=actual=(s_type*)malloc(sizeof(s_type));
        actual->id=1;
        strcpy(actual->host,server_settings.host);
        strcpy(actual->port_inc,server_settings.port_inc);

        f=freopen("./config/config.init", "w", stdout);
        fprintf(f, "%d\n%s\n%s\n\n",actual->id, actual->host, actual->port_inc);
        fclose(f);

        return server_settings;
    }

    while(fscanf(f,"%d\n%s\n%s\n\n",&r_id,r_host,r_port_inc)!=EOF){
        if(head==NULL) head=actual=(s_type*)malloc(sizeof(s_type));
        else actual=actual->next=(s_type*)malloc(sizeof(s_type));
        actual->next=NULL;
        actual->id=r_id;
        strcpy(actual->host,r_host);
        strcpy(actual->port_inc,r_port_inc);
    }

    printf(" List of available servers: \n");
    for(actual=head;actual!=NULL;actual=actual->next){
        printf("  #%d - %s:%s\n", actual->id, actual->host, actual->port_inc);
    }

    printf("Please choose one of the following servers or set up a new one (ID,New): ");
    fgets(select_inc, sizeof(select_inc), stdin);

    if(strncmp(select_inc,"New",3)==0){
        printf("Setting up a new connection!\n");
        server_settings = initialize_server();
        while (actual->next!=NULL){
            actual = actual->next;
        };
        actual->next=(s_type*)malloc(sizeof(s_type));
        actual=actual->next;
        actual->id=r_id+1;
        strcpy(server_settings.host,actual->host);
        strcpy(server_settings.port_inc,actual->port_inc);

        actual=head;
        f=freopen("./config/config.init", "w", stdout);
        while(actual){
            fprintf(f, "%d\n%s\n%s\n\n",actual->id, actual->host, actual->port_inc);
            actual = actual->next;
        }
        printf("New server configuration was saved in config.init!\n");
        fclose(f);

        return server_settings;
    }

    const char *tmp=select_inc;
    while(isdigit(*tmp) && *tmp++);

    actual=head;
    while(actual!=NULL){
        actual=actual->next;
        count++;
    }

    if (*tmp=='\0'){
        select = atoi(select_inc);
        while (1){
            if(select>count){
                printf("Not a valid server. Please try again!: ");
                fgets(select_inc, sizeof(select_inc), stdin);
            }
            if(select<=count){
                break;
            }
        }

        actual=head;
        count=0;

        while (actual != NULL){
            if (count == select){
                strcpy(server_settings.host,actual->host);
                strcpy(server_settings.port_inc,actual->port_inc);
                break;
            }
            count++;
            actual=actual->next;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return server_settings;
}
```

and Here are my structure declarations

```
struct data{
    char host[16];
    char port_inc[8];
};

typedef struct s_list{
    int id;
    char host[16];
    char port_inc[8];
    struct s_list *next;
} s_type;
```

Comment: Did you try to debug? On which line does it crash?

Comment: why don't you try using a debugger to figure out which line caused the segfault, GDB is a decent debugger on linux

Comment: `Segment fault` is because of tricky pointers, When you debug check pointers.

Comment: It crashes at freopen, fprintf functions. And does not seem to open the file at all. Of course i tried to debug but i dont know why does it crash at file opening, closing or writing.

Comment: Why don't you do any error checking? You can print an error message with `perror()`, the system automatically appends the reason why an error occured.

Comment: the posted function will fail because it is returning a variable that is on the stack..  Such a variable goes out-of-scope when the function exits.  Suggest using `malloc()` and returning the pointer that was returned from `malloc()`

Comment: most likely the call to `freopen()` failed.  The code needs to be performing error checking of `freopen()`,  and `fseek()` and `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: As I have explained in my answer passing `stdout` to `freopen` seems pointless.

Comment: `select` is a well known system function.  it is poor programming practice (and easily leads to confusion when the code is being read) to have variables the same name as a system function.

Comment: returning a non intrinsic value, such as a struct, is a poor programming practice and can lead to very obscure bugs that are a major pain to track down.   Suggest for non intrinsic values, like a struct, to return a pointer to the non intrinsic value.

Comment: If you create a function that inserts nodes, your code management would be easier.

Comment: for ease of documentation,  and ease of understanding by us humans, please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.   for readability, please separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a blank line

Comment: this line: `printf("Please choose one of the following servers or set up a new one (ID,New): ");` seems a bit misleading, as the list of available servers is before the current line on the display, not following the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just misused `freopen`.

This line :

```
f=freopen("./config/config.init", "w", stdout);
```

> `freopen` reopens an opened file in another mode.

You there open ./config/config.init file and then pass stdout as the opened file???

You just pass `f`.

So the code would be :

```
f=freopen("./config/config.init", "w", f);
```

This is just one error that I saw, You may have more errors!

Hope it helps.

Comment: Everything helps :D Thank you!

Comment: Naming variables a character is a bad thing to do ( it misleads ). You could name `f` to eg. `serverlstfile`.